# Is there an out-of-box PHP solution to do revision control for database fields?

Tags: php, mysql, version-control, controls, version

I'm looking for something that I can use to do versioning in PHP (not for code). I'd like to do revision control for a text input users edit.

I've found something great for Ruby (https://github.com/courtenay/acts_like_git) but can't find anything for PHP.

Does it not exist?

Comment: Could you use a trigger in the MySQL database to record the changes made by the user?

Answer (score 2):

You could use one of the ORM solutions that support versioning behavior. Both [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/behaviors%3Acore-behaviors%3Aversionable/en) and [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.6/WhatsNew#Versionablebehavior) support this, and there probably are even more.

Or maybe I misread your question, and you're looking for versioning of the model itself instead of versioning your data?

Answer (score 1):

This looks promising, but I don't know how well it works. Will you test it for me? :P

http://code.google.com/p/ruckusing/

Answer (score 0):

how about using a UNIQUE TIMESTAMP? This has to be refined, but you get my point.

Or do you want to keep track of the exact changes a user made to a huge text? I think it depends on what it exactly is you want to do, b/c versioning of real-language-texts might trigger conflicts that have to be resolved manually before the user can "commit" his change. Might be tough to establish ... but depends.

Best regards

Raffael

Comment: I think what he would like is a solution that keeps track on versions when updating a field, and one that does not require him to build the solution him self.

Comment: do you know what a TIMESTAMP is supposed to do?